# Forcing elements to contain to 100vh

Tags: css, flexbox

Why is the viewport not listening to the `height: 100vh' and still pushing the content to beyond it?

What is the best practise to achieve this without having to hardcode something like `calc(100vh - 21px)`?

**Edit**: margin seemed to be the issue here indeed. My working example is hard to find the margin because it uses ionic shadow dom elements and has loads of hidden CSS. I will try to backward engineer it tomorrow and try to find the problem. And publish the answer here with a better code example.

```css
body, html {height:100%; margin:0; padding: 0;}

menu {
  background-color: hsl(206, 68%, 96%);
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  background-color: hsl(206, 68%, 60%);
}

nav {
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: hsl(206, 68%, 40%)
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  background-color: hsl(206, 68%, 60%);
}
```

```html
<menu> 
  <header>
    Header
  </header>
  
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <footer>
    Footer
  </footer>
  
</menu>
```

Comment: It is `100vh`, not sure what you're expecting.

Comment: I am expecting it to contain to 100% of the viewport height. Not extending any further than the vh.

Comment: try max-height: 100vh and height: 100vh

Comment: I think you have a misunderstanding about `vh` its the browser viewheight and has nothing to do with it's parent DOM element. Please add your desired outcome.

Comment: Can you demonstrate the problem in your code snippet? Now the viewport height is `200px` and the `menu` element height is `200px`.

Comment: You have removed margins on html and body but not on other elements. Try margin: 0 on the menu,

Comment: @0stone0 I understand that, but vh is not the browser per se, but the viewport. So in the code editor here on stack overflow, it's not the browser, unless you expand it full-screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `margin: 0;` to `menu` to remove any default margin added by the browser:

```css
body, html {height:100%; margin:0; padding: 0;}

menu {
  background-color: hsl(206, 68%, 96%);
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: hsl(206, 68%, 60%);;
}

footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  background-color: hsl(206, 68%, 60%);
}
```

```html
<menu> 
  <header>
    Header
  </header>
  
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
      <li>Item</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  
  <footer>
    Footer
  </footer>
  
</menu>
```

Comment: Thanks, thats the issue here indeed. Is there an alternative for this? I have a react / ionic menu and works fine, until is scroll it smaller, it pushes the footer outside the menu for like 40 pixels and then stays there. That's the issue i am trying to figure out. But maybe i should try to rebuild it one by one and see when it starts occuring, because your example seems to be working fine.

Comment: That sounds like there is another rule for `menu` in a media query which applies a margin. You'd need to find that rule and add another one with at least the same specifity (i.e. same selector, including the media query) which resets the margin to 0 also for smaller screens.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit tricky because there are so many added hidden styles, such as env() variables and shadow dom elements. Only option is to backward engineer it and see when exactly the trouble arises. But at least i understand the problem now, so i marked your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the margin, from the parent div and make that container stay outside of the div that you want to give a margin, something like this:

```css
body {
 margin: 0px;
}

.sidebar {
 height: 100vh;
 width: 100px;
 position: fixed;
 background-color: red;
}

.container {
 width: 500px;
 margin-left: 150px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

.item {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: blue;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar"></div>
<div class="container">
<div class="item"> im on the side </div>
<div class="item"> im on the side </div>
<div class="item"> im on the side </div>
</div>
```